# Coroutines body does not cover in unit test code coverage - Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin-coroutines

When I run the unit test with code coverage, in the code coverage report lambda is shown as not covered.

[image: Code Coverage]

Below is my code:

```
open class CoroutineContextProvider {
    open val main: CoroutineContext by lazy { Dispatchers.Main }
    open val io: CoroutineContext by lazy { Dispatchers.IO }
}
```

```
class Hello (
    private val contextProvider: CoroutineContextProvider
) {
    private val mScope = CoroutineScope(contextProvider.main)

    var value: Int = 0

    fun test() {
        mScope.launch(contextProvider.io) {
            println("THIS LINE IS NOT COVERED IN CODE COVERAGE.")
            value++
        }
    }
}
```

```
class TestCoroutineContextProvider: CoroutineContextProvider() {
    override val main: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Unconfined
    override val io: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Unconfined
}
```

```
class CoroutineTestRule: TestRule {
    private val testCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    private val testCoroutineScope = TestCoroutineScope(testCoroutineDispatcher)

    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description?) = object: Statement() {
        override fun evaluate() {
            Dispatchers.setMain(testCoroutineDispatcher)
            base.evaluate()
            Dispatchers.resetMain()
            testCoroutineDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
        }
    }

    fun runBlockingTest(block: suspend TestCoroutineScope.() -> Unit) {
        testCoroutineScope.runBlockingTest { block() }
    }
}
```

```
class HelloTests {

    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val coroutineTestRule = CoroutineTestRule()

    @Test
    fun verify_test() = coroutineTestRule.runBlockingTest {
        val hello = Hello(TestCoroutineContextProvider())
        hello.test()
        assertTrue(hello.value == 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find anything? I face the same problem now.

Comment: Same here in a way all my suspend functions in the class do not show any coverage.

Comment: Any luck with solving this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to give it a try to the new code coverage tool developed by JetBrains called [Kover](https://youtu.be/jNu5LY9HIbw). In my brief experience with this tool, it works very well and is fully integrated with Kotlin and Gradle toolchain. The installation of the tool is quite easy, just follow [their guides](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover#quickstart).

I guess it depends on the JaCoCo plugin version you are using, but using the code input you got up there, these are my results related to that coroutine test:

#### JaCoCo (tool 0.8.7 plugin 0.16.0)

[image]

#### Kover (plugin 0.4.4)

[image]
[image]